# Find interior and closure of set

Tags: general-topology

Let $H=\left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 \leq1 \right \}\cap \mathbb{Q}^2\ $. Find Int($H$) and $\bar{H}$ (closure).

I think the closure is $H$ so we have to proof that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus H$ is an open set. Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus H$. Then we have $B((x,y), \epsilon )\cap H = \varnothing $, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$?

And know Int($H$) = $\left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 < 1 \right \}\cap \mathbb{Q}^2\ $?

Comment: You are waiting all from us, isn't it ? No accompanying sentences ? Just the text of the exercise ...

Comment: I think you mean to intersect with $\mathbb Q^2$ otherwise everything is empty.

Comment: Yes Justin, I forgot about that. I edited my question.

Comment: Assuming standard topology. $H$ is discrete so it can't have interior points.

Comment: @JeanMarie Question edited, certainly better now. You can be a little careful about being rude, it could have been to some people, but otherwise thanks for the prompt very much. That's kind of what I wish happens regularly.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon I hadn't the impression saying for example "You are awaiting all from us, isn't it ?" to be rude, just a trigerring question in order to generate a response such as "No, here is what I have done yet..."

Comment: @JeanMarie Sure, you are correct in your intentions. It's just that I don't want people who are doing the right things to face any kind of abuse whatsoever for the job that they do in helping MSE out, and a triggering statement could go both ways, I speak this way since recently I saw someone else leave a similar comment but receive some bad words in return. Keep going, thanks once again, I was only concerned that a bad response from OP or anybody should not mask your kind efforts here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball. Since $H\subseteq B$ we have $\mathrm{Cl}(H) \subseteq B$. Conversely, take $(x,y)\in B$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense, there exist sequences $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, where $(x_n,y_n)\in H$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{int}(H)=\emptyset$ as no non-empty open set of $\Bbb R^2$ can *only* contain rationals.

$\overline{H} = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$ by $\Bbb Q^2$ is dense in $\Bbb R^2$.